# Screen freezing with Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have issues with a Nvidia GPU that started three days ago. The screen freezes for maybe 0.5 seconds. It happens very frequently, like 5-10 times a minute.

I see following lines in dmesg:

```
[19215.886540] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: CMN (DP-2): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
[19430.008207] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: CMN (DP-2): G-SYNC Compatible: EDID min refresh rate invalid, disabling G-SYNC Compatible.
[19430.370034] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[19430.370099] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[19430.370134] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[19430.370166] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

I looked for solutions on Google but didn't find how to solve the issue.

```
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P1000 Mobile
System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Driver: Nvidia-driver-510
```

Comment: If it didn't happen before, it could be a bad cable or bad contact.

Comment: [This thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-21-10-failed-to-grab-modeset-ownership-with-495-44/193867/41) may be relevant.

Comment: had same problem with intermittent short freezes when using any kind of gpu accelerated application (even slack). tried two different 3060 cards, no luck. also nvidia-smi doesnt pick up the fan speed for some reason